# Neuronal Network doesnt recognize Handwritten Digits 28*28 Pixel MNIST Data set trained

Tags: python, keras, mnist

I have done a YT tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bte8Er0QhDg&t=1159s about creating a neuronal network which recognizes handwritten digits. It's trained with the mnist dataset and my network recognizes them all correctly. But when i show this network my own handwritten digits in paint, it does not recognize them. I did everything from asking chatgpt to rewriting re doing changing params etc. My image has the exact same shape and looks identical but it just will not recognize my digits ... Looking at my code what is missing why are my digits not recognized if the networks works well?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# My own data
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("handwritten.model")

img = cv2.imread("Digits/digit11.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_flat = gray.reshape(28, 28)

prediction = model.predict(np.expand_dims(img_flat, axis=0))
print(f"This digit is probably a {np.argmax(prediction)}")

# MNIST Data
prediction = model.predict(np.expand_dims(x_train[27], axis=0))
print(f"This digit is probably a {np.argmax(prediction)}")
```

Comment: Do you preprocess your data?

Comment: no my images are on black background, and written in white

Comment: I need more detail. Did you ensure that img_flat shows the same image as you drew?

Comment: Yes, when i show the image it has a puruple background and the number is in yellow, (i show it with plt.imshow(img_flat) ) just like the Digit from the mnist data set. Like i did everything which is done in the YT tutorials i think since they're made the framework has changed a little bit and thus its not working but its just a guess

Comment: but i figured out, that if i do not touch the boundaries of the frame, and use a 3px thick pen to draw i get a higher chance of a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was in reading the image file. Cv2 takes an inverse numbering of the pixels. What I mean is that in the zeros are 255 and 255s are zeros in your image. So you have to invert them.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()


x_train = x_train.astype(float)
x_test = x_test.astype(float)

x_train /= 255.0
x_test /= 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", 
metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

# My own data
# In[]

img = cv2.imread("Digits/digit11.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_flat = 255 - gray.reshape(28, 28).astype(float) # Here, you invert the values

img_flat /= 255.

prediction = model.predict(np.expand_dims(img_flat, axis=0))
print(f"This digit is probably a {np.argmax(prediction)}")
```

Comment: thank you, i also figured out through another youtuber that the numbers on mnist are all literally the same style and formatted so the network has troulbe finding own digits ...

Comment: Did it solve your problem? I could get correct predictions.

Comment: So, it's better to accept my answer as the correct answer so other people can find it easily if they have a similar problem.